# Regex paths in kubernetes Ingress not getting created as regex location in Nginx Ingress Controller

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

I am using Nginx Ingress Controller helm chart 0.6.0 and nginx ingress controller tag 1.8.0, kubernetes 1.15.

When I define a path in my Ingress which uses a regex, it does not work since it does  not get specified as a regex in the Nginx controller's configuration file location section.

I need to use a version of nginx ingress controller which additionally supports VirtualServer and VirtualServerRoutes.

```
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  namespace: ingress-test
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  rules:
  - host: test.any-xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /quack5/(.*)
        backend:
          serviceName: test
          servicePort: 80
```

When I apply this, the nginx ingress controller has set up the location as a non-regex expression

```
$ kubectl -n nginx-ingress-controller exec nginx-ingress-controller-nginx-ingress-79984b9747-8pl4w -- grep -R quack /etc/nginx/conf.d
$ /etc/nginx/conf.d/ingress-test-test-ingress.conf: location /quack5/(.*) {
```

I expect to see location ~* /quack5/(.*) {

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` annotation to your Nginx Ingress Controller definition file.

Delete `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex:  "true"` annotation.

**EDIT:**

I think the problem might be in the buildLocation function (&& location.Rewrite.Target != path). If the path and the `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` are equal the nginx Location is not prefixed with ~* and handled as regex.

```
    if len(location.Rewrite.Target) > 0 && location.Rewrite.Target != path {
        if path == slash {
            return fmt.Sprintf("~* %s", path)
        }
        // baseuri regex will parse basename from the given location
        baseuri := `(?<baseuri>.*)`
        if !strings.HasSuffix(path, slash) {
            // Not treat the slash after "location path" as a part of baseuri
            baseuri = fmt.Sprintf(`\/?%s`, baseuri)
        }
        return fmt.Sprintf(`~* ^%s%s`, path, baseuri)
    }

return path
```

I would suggest a directive to specify that the spec.rules.http.paths.path should end up as a regex Location, regardless of what `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` might be (even if it not specified). currently the only way to get the Location to be threatened as regex (added ~*) is to define a `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target` that is different from spec.rules.http.paths.path.

Please take a look: [ingress-regex](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1260#issuecomment-327104986),  [ingress-path-matching](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/), [path-not-threated-as-regex](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/issues/1260#issuecomment-327104986).

Comment: Thank you. I have not had success with this suggestion, I still see the same behavior. I have also tried image 1.8.1 without success.